# Export data from sharepoint database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In my sharepoint site, users save some data. Now I want to export the data. I know Export to Excel is available under List tab, but I want to do this in another way and I decided to access sharepoint database directly.

In SQL Server Management, I opened my site's database and there are many tables. In which table user data stored? There is no table named with my site's name.

I opened some tables but couldn't find the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways, but using SQL directly in case of SharePoint is bad.

You can use:

1. [Export to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-a-list-to-Excel-in-SharePoint-Online-40f4b5cd-cb8a-4106-817e-4a0bf7cd68b5)
2. [SQL Server Integration with SharePoint List Adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx)
3. [SharePoint .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST APIs](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)
4. [Sharepoint Search](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)
5. Direct SQL queries on SharePoint databases [Part I](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36432.sharepoint-2013-important-sql-queries-on-sharepoint-content-databases-part-i.aspx), [Part II](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36471.sharepoint-2013-important-sql-queries-on-sharepoint-content-databases-part-ii.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. In which table data that user save are stored?

Comment: Thanks, I found it.

Comment: happy it worked out for you. mark as answered if this resolves your issue